# How can I forward requests to http://server:port to http://server:port/app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, port, portforwarding

I'm adding a new service to one of the servers I am currently running, and I'm having troubles getting both applications to run nicely.

Currently I have an web application running on http://server.com:8080/ and I need to be able to forward any of those requests to http://server.com:8080/app (or something similar). I've tried to do some ProxyPass and ReverseProxyPass configurations but I do not understand apache2 well enough to understand what is going wrong.

Can someone provide me with information on how to accomplish this?

Comment: proxypass would only be for forwarding to some OTHER port/host. you're just redirecting to a sub-uri for the site. mod_write is probably all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a rewrite rule like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ^/app/$1
```